# svn import adds and commits a dir,but dir cant be browsed

Tags: svn

I have a project repos already under svn control on a machine on LAN.When i browse through the machine containing the repos... i can see the folders physically present at the repos path.

Then at sometime i imported a directory to the repos path....it added and commited it to the repos...but on browsing i cant see that dir at the repos path..

using svn list shows me that the imported directory exists and i can checkout it fine too...but why cant i browse it using the repos machine or sshing the repos machine?? is it hidden or something??

and if i remember it correctly once i had to add a new dir to the repos...i checked out the trunk with -N flag and then added the dir using svn add and committed it back...that way the dir did show when browsed...
so why are imported dirs hidden??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why would you want to browse your repo directly? As far as i know you can **CORRUPT** it if you're not careful.

check the code out and play with it locally

Answer (score 0):

What kind of method are you trying to browse it, and what URLs do you use to checkout your project?

Browsing using a web browser only makes sense if you're hosting the repository over http(s) using Apache.

Comment: i set up the repos on a linux rhel5.
by browsing i mean through terminal,nautilus or sshing from a linux machine.
though svn list shows that imported dir is present in repos,and can checkout it too..

Comment: if you perform a checkout, what's the URL you're using?

Comment: though i am using http protocol to checkout my code,the repos is being accessed on my company's LAN.its just than svn server is set up to use http for communicating... sorry for late response.